# How to render components in fake DOM in enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a components library and I have a `Tooltip` component that renders tooltip div at the very bottom of the document's body. How can I render the `Tooltip` component in a fake DOM and then test if the div element has appeared after I hovered `Tooltip` component?

So:

1. first I have to render/mount a Tooltip component first.
2. Simulate an event fe `wrapper.find('span').simulate('mouseenter')`
3. Check if the `<div>` element has appeared in a right place(as last body child).

I'm stuck on point 1 and 3. How can I test it in Jest/enzyme? Should I use JSDom?

Comment: What you are describing is a functional test. For that, it's better to use a framework like **nightwatch**. If you want to use enzyme then just test if the tooltip renders correctly, and with a simple unit test, test if the event is fired.

Comment: Thank you Ben for recommendig nightwatch- i'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way at seems to work, as Enzyme gives you globally document object you can refer to, out of the box:

```
test("shows tooltip when mouse enters child element", () => {
  const div = global.document.createElement("div");
  global.document.body.appendChild(div);

  const wrapper = mount(
    <Tooltip content="You got me!">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </Tooltip>,
    { attachTo: div }
  );

  wrapper.ref("overlay").simulate("mouseEnter");

  // do stuff...
});
```

The problem is with my component itself. This one is really complex and I don't know why during test it fires `onMouseLeave` just after I simulate `onMouseEnter`. But test works as I expected with some other more trivial tooltip component though Oo